# Rails 3.2.8 - How to get methods form application_controller.rb inside of a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following method in my controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private

  def check_api_credential(api_key)
    if Credential.find_by_key(api_key)
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

end
```

In all the controllers located directly under controllers folder, this method is reachable.

But the controllers files at controllers/api/v1/photos_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V1
    class PhotosController < ActionController::Base
      respond_to :json

      def create
        redirect_to root_url if check_api_credentials(params[:params][2])
        if Photo.create(params[:params][0])
          render 'success'
        else
          render 'failure'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to save I get 
     undefined method 'check_api_credentials'

How can I access those methods from application_controllers.rb? They are inside of controllers folder.

Answer (score 2):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

class PhotosController < ActionController::Base
```

Doesn't ring a bell? All other controllers "directly under controllers folder" are inherited from `ApplicationController`, but `PhotosController` is not a child of `ApplicationController`, it is its sibling. That's why it doesn't see the method.

Is there a reason why you didn't inherit `PhotosController` from `ApplicationController`?

Comment: I don't think I understood your point in the second question.

The same photos_controllers.rb in controllers/photos_controllers.rb do access that method and my point is how to make my controllers/api/v1/photos_controllers.rb to have the same access. I don't know how to do it. That's my point.

Comment: Inherit it from `ApplicationController`.

Comment: I tried adding include ApplicationController in different places and extend, but Rails always return that classes are not accepted in methods or methods are not accepted in classes for ApplicationController. I don't think your way works.

Comment: I meant this: `class PhotosController < ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller or where ever you need to call the private method in different location, you could try a `try:` method. So in your code,

```
  def create
    redirect_to root_url if try: check_api_credentials(params[:params][2])
    if Photo.create(params[:params][0])
      render 'success'
    else
      render 'failure'
    end
  end
```

It's might solve. Not sure... Just try to add this and run it....